# How to limit a LINQ left outer join to one row

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq, join

I have a left outer join (below) returning results as expected. I need to limit the results from the 'right' table to the 'first' hit. Can I do that somehow? Currently, I get a result for every record in both tables, I only want to see one result from the table on the left (items) no matter how many results I have in the right table (photos).

```
        var query = from i in db.items
                join p in db.photos
                on i.id equals p.item_id into tempPhoto
                from tp in tempPhoto.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby i.date descending 
                select new
                {
                    itemName = i.name,
                    itemID = i.id,
                    id = i.id,
                    photoID = tp.PhotoID.ToString()
                };


    GridView1.DataSource = query;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This will do the job for you.

```
from i in db.items
let p = db.photos.Where(p2 => i.id == p2.item_id).FirstOrDefault()
orderby i.date descending
select new
{
  itemName = i.name,
  itemID = i.id,
  id = i.id,
  photoID = p == null ? null : p.PhotoID.ToString();
}
```

I got this sql when I generated it against my own model (and without the name and second id columns in the projection).

```
SELECT [t0].[Id] AS [Id], CONVERT(NVarChar,(
    SELECT [t2].[PhotoId]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[PhotoId]
        FROM [dbo].[Photos] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[Item_Id] = ([t0].[Id])
        ) AS [t2]
    )) AS [PhotoId]
FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[Id] DESC
```

When I asked for the plan, it showed that the subquery is implemented by this join:

```
<RelOp LogicalOp="Left Outer Join" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops">
```

Comment: I like the elegance of this solution, however I think this may create a query that is harder for SQL to optimize because of the sub select

Comment: I checked and was happy both with the generated SQL and the estimated execution plan.  The subselect was planned to be a left outer join.

Comment: cool any chance you can post the SQL, I am curious to see it.

Comment: because I have been doing things with sub table groups. and if you way works I will be much happier with the slim code.  but like anything I want the best performing solution, not the prettiest.

Comment: not bad I have to give you props. would you mind running mine through, I don't have a model setup.  You should have enough rep to edit my comment, to add the execution plan.

Comment: Yes, there was a syntax error that I corrected in a later edit.  I forgot to specify a name for the parameter for that lambda.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I needed to get the latest (by date) of something from a child row that may not exist but I still need to return the parent row.  Since you can't have compound join clauses in LINQ and you can't test for null values on non-nullable columns, it was not working out well.  

     let ast = Context.AccountStatementTotal
      .Where(st => st.AccountNoId == a.AccountNoId)
      .OrderByDescending(st => st.Statementdt)
      .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: unfortunately it generates subquery, not LEFT JOIN... it's bad for performance

Comment: @vk_muse "When I asked for the plan, it showed that the subquery is implemented by this join"

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I still need to get the subquery (in this case photos) order by one of the fields with a ordery by case statement. Could you help me with that? because when I do .Where(p2 => i.id == p2.item_id).OrderBy(p2 => p2.FILELD == VALUE ? 1 : 0).FirstOrDefault() I get an error...

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is group the table.  The best way to do this is:

```
    var query = from i in db.items
                join p in (from p in db.photos
                           group p by p.item_id into gp
                           where gp.Count() > 0
                           select new { item_id = g.Key, Photo = g.First() })
            on i.id equals p.item_id into tempPhoto
            from tp in tempPhoto.DefaultIfEmpty()
            orderby i.date descending 
            select new
            {
                itemName = i.name,
                itemID = i.id,
                id = i.id,
                photoID = tp.Photo.PhotoID.ToString()
            };
```

---

Edit:  This is Amy B speaking.  I'm only doing this because Nick asked me to.  Nick, please modify or remove this section as you feel is appropriate.

The SQL generated is quite large.  The int 0 (to be compared with the count) is passed in via parameter.

```
SELECT [t0].X AS [id], CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX),(
    SELECT [t6].Y
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t5].Y
        FROM [dbo].[Photos] AS [t5]
        WHERE (([t4].Y IS NULL) AND ([t5].Y IS NULL)) OR (([t4].Y IS NOT NULL) AND ([t5].Y IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].Y = [t5].Y))
        ) AS [t6]
    )) AS [PhotoId]
FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [t0]
CROSS APPLY ((
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        ) AS [t1]
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT [t3].Y
        FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t2].Y
            FROM [dbo].[Photos] AS [t2]
            GROUP BY [t2].Y
            ) AS [t3]
        WHERE (([t0].X) = [t3].Y) AND ([t3].[value] > @p0)
        ) AS [t4])
ORDER BY [t0].Z DESC
```

The execution plan reveals three left joins.  At least one is trivial and should not be counted (it brings in the zero).  There is enough complexity here that I cannot clearly point to any problem for efficiency.  It might run great.

Comment: This may not of been the answer for Linq to SQL, but it did solve the problem for Entity Framework, with similar resultant sql. Looking for a better solution now.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
var q = from c in
          (from s in args
           select s).First()
        select c;
```

Around the last part of the query. Not sure if it will work or what kind of wack SQL it will produce  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner query. Include `DefaultIfEmpty` for the case of no photo and `orderby` for the case of more than one. The following example takes the photo with the greatest `id`.

```
var query = 
    from i in db.items
    let p = from p in db.photos where i.id == p.item_id orderby p.id select p).DefaultIfEmpty().Last()
    orderby i.date descending
    select new {
      itemName = i.name,
      itemID = i.id,
      id = i.id,
      photoID = p.PhotoID
    };
```

If you need to handle the case of no photo specially, you can omit `DefaultIfEmpty` and use `FirstOrDefault`/`LastOrDefault` instead.