# Entity Framework Core: How to perform a Join on `IQueryable` by selecting only the latest created records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, entity-framework-core

I am refactoring a code in production which create duplicates:

```cs
private IQueryable<CashoutModel> GetCashoutModels() =>
    from cashout in _context.Cashouts
    join audit in _context.Audits
        on cashout.Id.ToString() equals audit.EntityId
        into cashoutModel
    from audit in cashoutModel.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby cashout.CreatedOn descending
    select new CashoutModel
    {
        Id = cashout.Id,
        Amount = cashout.Amount,
        Comment = cashout.Comment,
        CreatedOn = cashout.CreatedOn,
        RecipientAccountId = cashout.RecipientAccountId,
        RecipientAccountName = cashout.RecipientAccountName,
        State = cashout.State,
        Reason = cashout.Reason,
        CreatedBy = audit == null 
            ? null 
            : audit.Name
    };
```

The `_context.Audits` actually records (use-triggered) changes that happen for certain records in `_context.Cashout`.

I am looking for a clean way to fix the current behavior of the `join` by selecting only (for a given `EntityId`) the latest audit record.

Comment: Would this link help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492683/how-to-limit-a-linq-left-outer-join-to-one-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you currently have is essentially doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which gets all the Cashouts records and the corresponding audit record.

*Assuming* you have a timestamp column (say **CreatedOn**) in the `Audits` table which captures when that audit record was created, you could use a [GROUP JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupJoin__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1____3__) here like so -

```
private IQueryable<CashoutModel> GetCashoutModels() =>
_context.Cashouts.GroupJoin(_context.Audits,
                            c => c.Id.ToString(),
                            a => a.EntityId,
                            (cashout, audit) => new CashoutModel
                                {
                                    Id = cashout.Id,
                                    Amount = cashout.Amount,
                                    Comment = cashout.Comment,
                                    CreatedOn = cashout.CreatedOn,
                                    RecipientAccountId = cashout.RecipientAccountId,
                                    RecipientAccountName = cashout.RecipientAccountName,
                                    State = cashout.State,
                                    Reason = cashout.Reason,
                                    CreatedBy = audit.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn)
                                                    .Select(y => y.Name)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault()
                                }).AsQueryable();
```